# Evaluate $\lim_{n\to\ \infty} \frac{3^{n+1} + 2^{n+2}}{3^{n-1} + 2^{n-2}} $

Tags: limits

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{3^{n+1} + 2^{n+2}}{3^{n-1} + 2^{n-2}}$$

As this is $\frac {\infty}{\infty}$ form, we can apply L'Hôpital's Rule but it isn't giving desired result. How can I proceed with it?

Comment: L'Hôpital's rule only applies to differentiable functions. What do you mean? Hint: factor out $3^{n}$

Comment: @ÉtienneBézout In fairness, these functions are arguably differentiable. It just happens that in this question, L'Hôpital's rule doesn't help because it doesn't provide simplifications like it otherwise might.

Comment: @πr8 Yes, if the domain is $\mathbb{R}$ or some appropriate subset thereof. Given that the variable $n$ was used I assumed we had $n \in \mathbb{N}$, but the limit is of course the same if we take $n \in \mathbb{R}$ and indeed then L'Hôpital would be applicable, although, as you point out, not useful.

Answer (score 5):

Divide numerator and denominator by $3^n$:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3^{n+1}+2^{n+2}}{3^{n-1}+2^{n-2}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3+4\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n}{\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n}=\frac{3+0}{\frac{1}{3}+0}=9.
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3^{n+1}+2^{n+2}}{3^{n-1}+2^{n-2}}=$$

---

The leading term in the denominator is $3^{n-1}$. Divide the numerator and denominator by this:

---

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{9+2^{n+2}3^{1-n}}{1+2^{n-2}3^{1-n}}=\frac{9+0}{1+0}=\frac{9}{1}=9$$

Answer (score 1):

The leading term in the denominator is $3^{n-1}$

Divide the numerator and denominator by $3^{n-1}$

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\overbrace{2^{n+2}3^{1-n}}^{\to 0}+9}{\underbrace{2^{n-2}3^{1-n}}_{\to 0}+1}=\frac{0+9}{0+1}=\color{red}9$$

Answer (score 0):

One may write, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
 \frac{3^{n+1} + 2^{n+2}}{3^{n-1} + 2^{n-2}}= \frac{3 + 4\times(2/3)^{n}}{\frac13 + \frac14\times(2/3)^{n}}
$$ and conclude.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{n\to\ \infty} \frac{3^{n+1} + 2^{n+2}}{3^{n-1} + 2^{n-2}} $$
$$=\lim_{n\to\ \infty} \frac{3^{2} +2^3 (\frac{2}{3})^{n-1}}{1 + \frac{1}{2}(\frac{2}{3})^{n-1}}$$
$$=\frac{3^2+8 \cdot 0}{1+\frac{1}{2} \cdot 0}$$
$$=9$$

Answer (score 0):

Use *equivalents*:

The numerator is $\;3\cdot 3^n+4\cdot 2^n\sim_\infty 3\cdot 3^n$, while the denominator is $\;\frac13 3^n+\frac14 2^n\sim_\infty \frac13\cdot 3^n$, whence 
$$\frac{3^{n+1}+2^{n+2}}{3^{n-1}+2^{n-2}}\sim \frac{3^{n+1}}{3^{n-1}}=9.$$

Answer (score 0):

Using equivalent infinitesimals, we have
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{3^{n+1} + 2^{n+2}}{3^{n-1} + 2^{n-2}}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{3^{n+1}}{3^{n-1}}=9$$